# RFC 7239 - Difference between 'by' and 'host'

Tags: http, proxy, rfc

Im in the process of implementing a RFC 7239 compatible `forwarded` header in an internal reverse proxy. In brief, the specification states that the values of the host and by components should be as follows:

- `host` - the value of the host header as received by the proxy
- `by` - the user agent facing interface of the proxy

Whats the difference between these two? If i have a proxy server facing the internet on the address `http://myexampleserver.com`, as i understand it both host and by would have the same value?

Answer (score 1):

No, the original request will contain the requested site's DNS address as `host` header, not the proxy's DNS address.

The RFC [mentions](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7239#section-5.3) this `host` value's intended use:

> This can be used, for example, by the origin
> server if a reverse proxy is rewriting the "Host" header field to
> some internal host name.

So, for example:

- User agent requests http://example.com/foo through proxy http://yourexampleproxy/. Request will contain `GET / http://example.com/foo` and `Host: example.com`.
- Your proxy translates, by configuration, the `Host: example.com` header to `Host: some-internal-foo`, and adds the `Forwarded: host=example.com;by=yourexampleproxy` header, so the origin server can inspect it.